# ChartJS 4.X.X Integration in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, chartjs

I'm trying to integrate chart.js version 4 or upper into a lwc but I'm not able to do it.

I did it with previous versions until 2.9.X that were distributed as a zip with just a .js and a .css file. With new distributions I tried to import the /dist/chart.js file to my component but i'm getting "Cannot use import statement outside a module" .

Any clue about which file should I add as a static resource and how to import it ?

Thanks in advance.

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

import {
    loadScript
} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';


import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/chartJs';



export default class CommunityGlobalChart extends LightningElement {

  createChart() {
  //whatever
  }

    renderedCallback() {
        let self = this;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, chartjs + '/dist/chart.js')
              
            ])
            .then(() => {
                self.createChart();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
            });
    }
}
```